# What does *kata* mean in the sentence provided below?

Tags: meaning

乗車券をお求めになるかたは、どうぞこちらへ。
joushaken o omotome ni naru kata wa, douzo kochira e.
Those who want to buy passenger ticket please go this way.

Is it 型 (かた), which means type or model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, kata is the polite (honorific) form of 'hito' (person, or people).

Comment: Great thanks. One question though. By that logic, *joushaken o omotome ni naru* modifies *kata*. But then, shouldn't there be a particle that relates them together,  like *no*?

Comment: Not necessary, as a noun can follow a verb just as it can an adjective. For example, おもしろい人 (an interesting person) and おもしろい話をする人 (a person who tells interesting stories)

Comment: Oh yeah. I almost forgot. Very many thanks.